# Работа с LIMIT в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Имеем запрос

```
$sql = 
"SELECT t.id FROM `tours`  AS t
  RIGHT JOIN `tourscountries` AS cn 
          ON t.id = cn.tours_id 
         AND cn.country in ([countries])
  RIGHT JOIN `toursprices` AS pr  
          ON t.id = pr.tours_id 
         AND pr.date >= '[datefrom]' 
         AND pr.date <= '[datebefore]' 
         AND pr.price >= [pricefrom] 
         AND pr.price <= [pricebefore]
  RIGHT JOIN `toursfrom` AS tf  
          ON t.id = tf.tours_id 
         AND tf.from in([from])
  WHERE t.typetour in ([typetour]) 
    AND t.typetransport in ([typetransport]) 
    AND t.nightcount >= [nightfrom] 
    AND t.nightcount <= [nightbefore] 
  LIMIT 0,10;";
```

Он выведет все id в которых будут вхождения ( то есть некоторые id могут попасть более чем по 1 разу), мне же нужно вывести 10 уникальных по ID на страницу (а так лимит отрабает на 100 выведенных результатов(а там могут быть одинаковые id))

Comment: Вариантов несколько, самые простые: добавить `group by t.id` или `distinct t.id`, но по скорости может хромать

Comment: господи я забыл про distinct, оформляй как ответ)

Comment: Вижу, ответ дан. Но хочется добавить пару замечаний.
С Limit всегда используйте order by иначе результат может быть непредсказуем. И да Right Join? Вы серьезно? А подругоме не пробовали переписать? Просто его никто не использует и как-то нет в нем необходимости в нормальных случаях, все обычно на Left'ах делается =)

Comment: Ответ писать смысла нет - таких вопросов здесь куча, надо определиться только какой вопрос имеет лучшие ответы, чтобы этот закрыть как дубликат. Насчет сортировки - если указано `GROUP BY`, то автоматически включается сортировка по полям из group. Насчет `distinct` не уверен - может быть тоже сортирует, а может и нет

Comment: там юзается инер это попробывал)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(t.id)`

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы выбрать уникальные значения надо в запрос добавить `DISTINCT`:
`SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM table` и уже дальше обрабатывать значения